# jQuery idTabs plugin tab click function

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, idtabs

When using the idTabs jQuery plugin how do you add function that is called when a tab is clicked?  The documentation says this (but gives no example):

```
click (function) 
Function will be called when a tab is clicked. ex: $(...).idTabs(foo) 
If the function returns true, idTabs will show/hide content (as usual). 
If the function returns false, idTabs will not take any action. 
The function is passed four variables: 
  The id of the element to be shown 
  an array of all id's that can be shown 
  the element containing the tabs 
  and the current settings
```

My code:

```
<ul class="idTabs"> 
  <li><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#official">Tabs 3</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div id="jquery">If you haven't checked out ...</div> 
<div id="official">idTabs is only a simple ...</div>

function tabChanged(id, tabs, parent, settings) {
    alert('tabChanged');
    return true;
}

$(".idTabs").idTabs(tabChanged);
```

Nothing happens when the tab is clicked - I would expect to seen an alert message

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there. You can do it like:

```
$(".idTabs").idTabs({click: tabChanged});
```

Or you can use an anonymous function:

```
$('.idTabs').idTabs({
    click: function(id, all, container, settings){
        alert('tabChanged');
        return true;
    }
});
```